# Does this Java projects follow the MVC pattern?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, service, model, controller

I am writing the Restaurant Management homework which must be following the MVC pattern. My `Menu` model has two parts: drink menu and food menu.

With food menu, it separates into three different types of menu: Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner menu. About the drink menu, it also divide into two different menu: Alcohol and Soft drink menu.

Each menu has the same CRUD operation therefore, I wrote one father class and extend five models from it, therefore, I only need to write one method for father class and change the parameter for methods and they will work the same way.

However, I don't know that my structure has been following the MVC structure or not? And should I write the exception handling in the View of MVC structure or should I write it in controller? Thanks for your support.

**My supper models :**

```
public class DailyMenu implements Serializable {
        private List<MenuItem> menuItemList;
        public DailyMenu(List<MenuItem> menuItemList){
            this.menuItemList = menuItemList;
        }
        public DailyMenu(){
            this.menuItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        public List<MenuItem> getMenuItemList() {
            return menuItemList;
        }
    
        public void setMenuItemList(List<MenuItem> menuItemList) {
            this.menuItemList = menuItemList;
        }
    }
```

**Menu View:**

```
public class MenuView {
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private DailyMenuServices dailyMenuServices = new DailyMenuServicesImpl();


    public DailyMenu getMenuTypes(Menu menu){;
        menu();
        int option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        MenuTypes menuTypes = MenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (menuTypes){
            case FOODMENU -> {return getFoodMenuTypes(menu.getFoodMenu());}
            case DRINKMENU -> {return getDrinkMenuTypes(menu.getDrinkMenu());}
            default -> {return null;}
        }
    }
    public DailyMenu getFoodMenuTypes(FoodMenu foodMenu){
        foodMenu();
        int option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        FoodMenuTypes foodMenuTypes = FoodMenuTypes.get(option-1);

        switch (foodMenuTypes){
            case BREAKFASTMENU -> {return foodMenu.getBreakfastMenu();}
            case LUNCHMENU -> {return foodMenu.getLunchMenu();}
            case DINNERMENU -> {return foodMenu.getDinnerMenu();}
            default -> {return null;}
        }
    }
    public DailyMenu getDrinkMenuTypes(DrinkMenu drinkMenu){
        drinkMenu();
        int option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        DrinkMenuTypes drinkMenuTypes = DrinkMenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (drinkMenuTypes){
            case ALCOHOL -> { return drinkMenu.getAlcohol();}
            case SOFTDRINK -> {return drinkMenu.getSoftDrinks();}
            default -> {return null;}
        }
    }
    public MenuItem createMenuItem(){
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        System.out.print("\n Insert food name: ");
        menuItem.setNames(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print(" Insert food description: ");
        menuItem.setDescription(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print(" Insert food image: ");
        menuItem.setImage(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print(" Insert food price: ");
        menuItem.setPrice(Float.parseFloat(scanner.nextLine()));
        return menuItem;
    }
    public String getMenuItemName(){
        System.out.print("Insert Menu item you want to change: ");
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public static void menu(){
        System.out.println("\n 1. Food Menu");
        System.out.println(" 2. Drink Menu");
        System.out.print(" Choose your option:");
    }
    public static void drinkMenu(){
        System.out.println("1. Alcohol Menu");
        System.out.println("2. Soft drink Menu");
        System.out.print("Choose which menu you want to make change:");
    }
    public static void foodMenu(){
        System.out.println("\n1. Breakfast Menu");
        System.out.println("2. Lunch Menu");
        System.out.println("3. Dinner Menu");
        System.out.print("\nChoose which menu you want to add:");
    }
}
```

**My Menu Service:**

```
public class DailyMenuServicesImpl implements DailyMenuServices {
    @Override
    public void addMenuItemsToMenu(DailyMenu dailyMenu,MenuItem menuItem) {
        List<MenuItem> menuItemList = dailyMenu.getMenuItemList();
        menuItemList.add(menuItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMenu(DailyMenu dailyMenu,MenuItem updateMenuItem,String itemName) {

        dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().forEach((MenuItem menuItem)->{
            if(menuItem.getNames().equals(itemName)){
                dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().set(dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().indexOf(menuItem),updateMenuItem);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteMenu(DailyMenu dailyMenu,String itemName) {
        dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().removeIf(menuItem ->
                menuItem.getNames().equals(itemName));
    }
}
```

**My Main method:**

```
    public class Main {
        private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            int option;
            Menu menu = new Menu();
            Bill bill = new Bill();
            while (true){
                System.out.println("\n1.Menu management");
                System.out.println("2.Bill management");
                System.out.print("Please choose which types Management you want to work with:");
                option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                ManagementTypes types = ManagementTypes.get(option-1);
                switch (types){
                    case MENU -> menuMain(menu);
                    case BILL -> billMain(bill,menu);
                    default -> {}
                }
            }
        }
        public static void billMain(Bill bill, Menu menu) throws IOException{
            int option = 0;
            BillServices billServices = new BillServicesImpl();
            BillPrinter billPrinter = new BillPrinterImpl();
            BillFileHandlingServices billFileHandlingServices = new BillFileHandlingServicesImpl();
            MenuView menuView = new MenuView();
            BillView billView = new BillView();
            MenuPrinter menuPrinter = new MenuPrinterImpl();
            try {
                while (option != 7){
    
                    System.out.println("\nBill management");
                    System.out.println("1. Create Bill ");
                    System.out.println("2. Update Bill ");
                    System.out.println("3. Delete Bill");
                    System.out.println("4. Show Bill");
                    System.out.println("5. Export bill");
                    System.out.println("6. Import bill");
                    System.out.println("7. To escape");
                    System.out.print("\nChoose your option:");
                    option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    
                    ManagementActions actions = ManagementActions.get(option-1);
                    switch (actions){
                        case CREATE -> {
                            menuPrinter.printMenu(menu);
                            DailyMenu dailyMenu = menuView.getMenuTypes(menu);
                            menuPrinter.printMenu(dailyMenu);
                            BillItems billItems = billView.createBillItem(dailyMenu);
                            billServices.addBill(bill,billItems);
                        }
                        case UPDATE -> {
                            billPrinter.printBill(bill);
                            DailyMenu dailyMenu = menuView.getMenuTypes(menu);
                            BillItems billItems = billView.createBillItem(dailyMenu);
                            String itemName = billView.getBillItemName();
                            billServices.updateBill(bill,billItems,itemName);
                        }
                        case DELETE -> {
                            billPrinter.printBill(bill);
                            String itemName = billView.getBillItemName();
                            billServices.deleteBillItems(bill,itemName);
                        }
                        case SHOW -> billPrinter.printBill(bill);
                        case EXPORT -> billFileHandlingServices.exportBill(bill);
                        case IMPORT -> {
                            Bill importBill = billFileHandlingServices.importBill();
                            billPrinter.printBill(importBill);
                        }
                        case BREAK -> {}
                    }
                }
            }catch (NullPointerException | IllegalStateException | InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException exception){
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
        public static void menuMain(Menu menu) throws IOException{
            int option = 0;
            DailyMenuServices dailyMenuServices = new DailyMenuServicesImpl();
            MenuView menuView = new MenuView();
            MenuPrinter menuPrinter = new MenuPrinterImpl();
            MenuFileHandlingServices menuFileHandlingServices = new MenuFileHandlingServicesImpl();
            try {
                while (option != 7) {
                    System.out.println("\nMenu management");
                    System.out.println("1. Create Menu Items");
                    System.out.println("2. Update Menu Items");
                    System.out.println("3. Delete Menu Items");
                    System.out.println("4. Show Menu Items");
                    System.out.println("5. Export Menu");
                    System.out.println("6. Import Menu");
                    System.out.println("7. To escape");
                    System.out.print("\nChoose your option:");
                    option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                    ManagementActions actions = ManagementActions.get(option - 1);
                    switch (actions) {
                        case CREATE -> {
                            MenuItem menuItem = menuView.createMenuItem();
                            DailyMenu dailyMenu = menuView.getMenuTypes(menu);
                            dailyMenuServices.addMenuItemsToMenu(dailyMenu,menuItem);
                        }
                        case UPDATE -> {
                            menuPrinter.printMenu(menu);
                            MenuItem menuItem = menuView.createMenuItem();
                            DailyMenu dailyMenu = menuView.getMenuTypes(menu);
                            menuPrinter.printMenu(dailyMenu);
                            String itemName = menuView.getMenuItemName();
                            dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(dailyMenu,menuItem,itemName);
                        }
                        case DELETE -> {
                            menuPrinter.printMenu(menu);
                            DailyMenu dailyMenu = menuView.getMenuTypes(menu);
                            menuPrinter.printMenu(dailyMenu);
                            String itemName = menuView.getMenuItemName();
                            dailyMenuServices.deleteMenu(dailyMenu,itemName);
                        }
                        case SHOW -> menuPrinter.printMenu(menu);
                        case EXPORT -> menuFileHandlingServices.exportMenu(menu);
                        case IMPORT -> {
                            Menu importMenu = menuFileHandlingServices.importMenu();
                            menuPrinter.printMenu(importMenu);
                        }
                        case BREAK -> {}
                    }
                }
            }catch (NullPointerException | IllegalStateException | NumberFormatException exception){
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

**Main class:**

```
public static void menuMain(Menu menu) throws IOException{
        int option = 0;
        MenuControllers menuControllers =  new MenuControllers();
        MenuPrinter menuPrinter = MenuPrinterImpl.getInstance();

        try {
            while (option != 7) {

                menu();
                option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

                ManagementActions actions = ManagementActions.get(option - 1);
                switch (actions) {
                    case CREATE -> menuControllers.add(menu);
                    case UPDATE ->menuControllers.update(menu);
                    case DELETE -> menuControllers.delete(menu);
                    case SHOW -> menuControllers.showMenu(menu);
                    case EXPORT -> menuControllers.exportFile(menu);
                    case IMPORT -> {
                        Menu importMenu = menuControllers.importFile();
                        menuControllers.showMenu(importMenu);
                    }
                    case BREAK -> {}
                }
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException | IllegalStateException | NumberFormatException exception){
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void menu(){
        System.out.println("\nMenu management");
        System.out.println("1. Create Menu Items");
        System.out.println("2. Update Menu Items");
        System.out.println("3. Delete Menu Items");
        System.out.println("4. Show Menu Items");
        System.out.println("5. Export Menu");
        System.out.println("6. Import Menu");
        System.out.println("7. To escape");
        System.out.print("\nChoose your option:");
    }
```

**My Menu controller:**

```
public class MenuControllers {
    private final MenuView view;
    private final DailyMenuServices  dailyMenuServices;
    private final MenuFileHandlingServices menuFileHandlingServices ;
    public MenuControllers(){
        this.view  = MenuView.getInstance();
        this.dailyMenuServices = DailyMenuServicesImpl.getInstance();
        this.menuFileHandlingServices = MenuFileHandlingServicesImpl.getInstance();
    }

    public void add(Menu menu){
        MenuItem  menuItem = view.createMenuItem();
        int option = view.getMenuTypes();
        MenuTypes menuTypes = MenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (menuTypes){
            case FOODMENU -> addToFoodMenu(menu.getFoodMenu(),menuItem);
            case DRINKMENU -> addToDrinkMenu(menu.getDrinkMenu(),menuItem);
        }
    }
    public void addToDrinkMenu(DrinkMenu drinkMenu, MenuItem menuItem){
        int option = view.getDrinkMenuTypes();
        DrinkMenuTypes drinkMenuTypes = DrinkMenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (drinkMenuTypes){
            case ALCOHOL -> dailyMenuServices.addMenuItemsToMenu(drinkMenu.getAlcohol(),menuItem);
            case SOFTDRINK -> dailyMenuServices.addMenuItemsToMenu(drinkMenu.getSoftDrinks(),menuItem);
        }
    }

    public void addToFoodMenu(FoodMenu foodMenu, MenuItem menuItem){
        int option = view.getFoodMenuTypes();
        FoodMenuTypes foodMenuTypes = FoodMenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (foodMenuTypes){
            case BREAKFASTMENU -> dailyMenuServices.addMenuItemsToMenu(foodMenu.getBreakfastMenu(),menuItem);
            case LUNCHMENU -> dailyMenuServices.addMenuItemsToMenu(foodMenu.getLunchMenu(),menuItem);
            case DINNERMENU -> dailyMenuServices.addMenuItemsToMenu(foodMenu.getDinnerMenu(),menuItem);
        }
    }

    public void update(Menu menu){
        view.printMenu(menu);
        String foodName = view.getMenuItemName();
        MenuItem  menuItem = view.createMenuItem();
        int option = view.getMenuTypes();
        MenuTypes menuTypes = MenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (menuTypes){
            case FOODMENU -> updateToFoodMenu(menu.getFoodMenu(),menuItem,foodName);
            case DRINKMENU -> updateToDrinkMenu(menu.getDrinkMenu(),menuItem,foodName);
        }
    }
    public void updateToDrinkMenu(DrinkMenu drinkMenu, MenuItem menuItem,String foodName){
        int option = view.getDrinkMenuTypes();
        DrinkMenuTypes drinkMenuTypes = DrinkMenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (drinkMenuTypes){
            case ALCOHOL -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(drinkMenu.getAlcohol(),menuItem,foodName);
            case SOFTDRINK -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(drinkMenu.getSoftDrinks(),menuItem,foodName);
        }
    }

    public void updateToFoodMenu(FoodMenu foodMenu, MenuItem menuItem,String foodName){
        int option = view.getFoodMenuTypes();
        FoodMenuTypes foodMenuTypes = FoodMenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (foodMenuTypes){
            case BREAKFASTMENU -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(foodMenu.getBreakfastMenu(),menuItem,foodName);
            case LUNCHMENU -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(foodMenu.getLunchMenu(),menuItem,foodName);
            case DINNERMENU -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(foodMenu.getDinnerMenu(),menuItem,foodName);
        }
    }

    public void delete(Menu menu){
        view.printMenu(menu);
        String foodName = view.getMenuItemName();
        int option = view.getMenuTypes();
        MenuTypes menuTypes = MenuTypes.get(option-1);

        switch (menuTypes){
            case FOODMENU -> deleteToFoodMenu(menu.getFoodMenu(),foodName);
            case DRINKMENU -> deleteToDrinkMenu(menu.getDrinkMenu(),foodName);
        }
    }
    public void deleteToDrinkMenu(DrinkMenu drinkMenu,String foodName){
        int option = view.getDrinkMenuTypes();
        DrinkMenuTypes drinkMenuTypes = DrinkMenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (drinkMenuTypes){
            case ALCOHOL -> dailyMenuServices.deleteMenu(drinkMenu.getAlcohol(),foodName);
            case SOFTDRINK -> dailyMenuServices.deleteMenu(drinkMenu.getSoftDrinks(),foodName);
        }
    }

    public void deleteToFoodMenu(FoodMenu foodMenu,String foodName){
        int option = view.getFoodMenuTypes();
        FoodMenuTypes foodMenuTypes = FoodMenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (foodMenuTypes){
            case BREAKFASTMENU -> dailyMenuServices.deleteMenu(foodMenu.getBreakfastMenu(),foodName);
            case LUNCHMENU -> dailyMenuServices.deleteMenu(foodMenu.getLunchMenu(),foodName);
            case DINNERMENU -> dailyMenuServices.deleteMenu(foodMenu.getDinnerMenu(),foodName);
        }
    }
    public void showMenu(Menu menu){
        view.printMenu(menu);
    }
    public void exportFile(Menu menu) throws IOException {
        menuFileHandlingServices.exportMenu(menu);
    }

    public Menu importFile() throws IOException {
        return menuFileHandlingServices.importMenu();
    }
}
```

**My Menu view:**

```
public class MenuView {
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final MenuPrinter menuPrinter = MenuPrinterImpl.getInstance();

    private MenuView(){ }
    public static MenuView getInstance(){

        return MenuViewHelper.menuView;
    }
    public static class MenuViewHelper{
        private static final MenuView menuView = new MenuView();
    }
    public int getMenuTypes(){
        menu();
        return Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    public int getFoodMenuTypes(){
        foodMenu();
        return Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    public int getDrinkMenuTypes(){
        drinkMenu();
        return Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    public MenuItem createMenuItem(){
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        System.out.print("\n Insert food name: ");
        menuItem.setNames(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print(" Insert food description: ");
        menuItem.setDescription(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print(" Insert food image: ");
        menuItem.setImage(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print(" Insert food price: ");
        menuItem.setPrice(Float.parseFloat(scanner.nextLine()));
        return menuItem;
    }
    public String getMenuItemName(){
        System.out.print("Insert Menu item you want to change: ");
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }
    public void printMenu(Menu menu){
        menuPrinter.printMenu(menu);
    }

    public static void menu(){
        System.out.println("\n 1. Food Menu");
        System.out.println(" 2. Drink Menu");
        System.out.print(" Choose your option:");
    }
    public static void drinkMenu(){
        System.out.println("1. Alcohol Menu");
        System.out.println("2. Soft drink Menu");
        System.out.print("Choose which menu you want to use:");
    }
    public static void foodMenu(){
        System.out.println("\n1. Breakfast Menu");
        System.out.println("2. Lunch Menu");
        System.out.println("3. Dinner Menu");
        System.out.print("\nChoose which menu you want to use:");
    }

}
```

**My new Menu service:**

```
public class DailyMenuServicesImpl implements DailyMenuServices {

    private DailyMenuServicesImpl(){}
    public static DailyMenuServicesImpl getInstance(){
        return DailyMenuServicesImplHelper.dailyMenuServicesImpl;
    }
    private static class DailyMenuServicesImplHelper{
        private static final DailyMenuServicesImpl dailyMenuServicesImpl = new DailyMenuServicesImpl();
    }
    @Override
    public void addMenuItemsToMenu(DailyMenu dailyMenu,MenuItem menuItem) {
        List<MenuItem> menuItemList = dailyMenu.getMenuItemList();
        menuItemList.add(menuItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMenu(DailyMenu dailyMenu,MenuItem updateMenuItem,String itemName) {
        dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().stream()
                                    .filter(menuItem -> menuItem.getNames().equals(itemName))
                                    .findFirst()
                                    .ifPresentOrElse(menuItem -> {
                                        menuItem.setNames(updateMenuItem.getNames());
                                        menuItem.setPrice(updateMenuItem.getPrice());
                                        menuItem.setDescription(updateMenuItem.getDescription());
                                        menuItem.setImage(updateMenuItem.getImage());
                                    },()->{
                                        throw new NullPointerException("Wrong menu Item name !!!");
                                    });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteMenu(DailyMenu dailyMenu,String itemName) {
        dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().removeIf(menuItem ->
                menuItem.getNames().equals(itemName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (**M**odel - **V**iew - **C**ontroller) is a pattern which separates data modelling from view rendering from action controlling. What are the tasks of the three:

**model**: it is responsible for representing the data accurately
**view**: it is responsible for the interactions with the user

- UI rendering when UI exists or console messages in the case of CLI
- Event handling
- input parsing
  **controller**: it is responsible in understanding what the user command is meaning and invoking the correct behavior (action)

So, in order to determine whether your code complies to the MVC pattern we will need to read your model, view and controller code and see how much they fulfill the above.

From a purely MVC-pattern point of view, your Model already fulfills the criteria, but your View has some business logic inside it which would fit more into the controller. Let's see a few examples:

```
    public void updateMenuTypes(Menu menu){
        menu();
        int option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        MenuTypes menuTypes = MenuTypes.get(option-1);
        System.out.println("Insert Menu item you want to change: ");
        String itemName = scanner.nextLine();
        MenuItem menuItem = createMenuItem();

        switch (menuTypes){
            case FOODMENU -> updateFoodMenuTypes(menu.getFoodMenu(),menuItem,itemName);
            case DRINKMENU -> updateDrinkMenuTypes(menu.getDrinkMenu(),menuItem,itemName);
        }
    }
    public void updateFoodMenuTypes(FoodMenu foodMenu,MenuItem menuItem,String itemName){
        foodMenu();
        int option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        FoodMenuTypes foodMenuTypes = FoodMenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (foodMenuTypes){
            case BREAKFASTMENU -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(foodMenu.getBreakfastMenu(),menuItem,itemName);
            case LUNCHMENU -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(foodMenu.getLunchMenu(),menuItem,itemName);
            case DINNERMENU -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(foodMenu.getDinnerMenu(),menuItem,itemName);
        }
    }
    public void updateDrinkMenuTypes(DrinkMenu drinkMenu,MenuItem menuItem, String itemName){
        drinkMenu();
        int option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        DrinkMenuTypes drinkMenuTypes = DrinkMenuTypes.get(option-1);

        switch (drinkMenuTypes){
            case ALCOHOL -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(drinkMenu.getAlcohol(),menuItem,itemName);
            case SOFTDRINK -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(drinkMenu.getSoftDrinks(),menuItem,itemName);
        }
    }
```

A recurring pattern is the following:

- you call a menu method (`menu`, `foodmenu` or `drinkmenu`, respectively)
- the menu method asks a question towards the user
- and your view determines what to call

The first two of the above are valid parts of the View, because they handle the UI (that is, they ask a question towards a user and getting an input), but the logic which determines what to call is a better fit into the Controller part. For example, this part:

```
        FoodMenuTypes foodMenuTypes = FoodMenuTypes.get(option-1);
        switch (foodMenuTypes){
            case BREAKFASTMENU -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(foodMenu.getBreakfastMenu(),menuItem,itemName);
            case LUNCHMENU -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(foodMenu.getLunchMenu(),menuItem,itemName);
            case DINNERMENU -> dailyMenuServices.updateMenu(foodMenu.getDinnerMenu(),menuItem,itemName);
        }
```

Is business logic that handles menu updates and you should move this logic into a controller method. The idea is to separate business logic from the view rendering. Imagine the case that at some point you will need to write a Swing UI for this project and you will need to totally rewrite anything related to your view. If in your view code you have business logic, then you will have a hard time doing so. If your view code is properly separated from the controller code, then, in such a scenario you will only need to look at how the controller receives the input from the view and rewrite the view (**and only the view**) in such a way that it will comply to the expectations of the controller.

You also mix up view and controller inside your controller, namely at

```
    @Override
    public void updateMenu(DailyMenu dailyMenu,MenuItem updateMenuItem,String itemName) {
        menuPrinter.printMenu(dailyMenu);

        dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().forEach((MenuItem menuItem)->{
            if(menuItem.getNames().equals(itemName)){
                dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().set(dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().indexOf(menuItem),updateMenuItem);
            }
        });
    }
```

The call to `menuPrinter.printMenu(dailyMenu);` is clearly view rendering and it would be better to make that call inside the view, after the controller finished its job if you want to apply the MVC pattern. It's also better not to display the main menu before the controller finished its job (unless you have a very good reason for it), because your command may fail and it will nevertheless suggest it was successful if the user is asked for the next action. So, you could refactor this method as follows:

```
    @Override
    public DailyMenu updateMenu(DailyMenu dailyMenu,MenuItem updateMenuItem,String itemName) {

        dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().forEach((MenuItem menuItem)->{
            if(menuItem.getNames().equals(itemName)){
                dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().set(dailyMenu.getMenuItemList().indexOf(menuItem),updateMenuItem);
            }
        });

        return dailyMenu;
    }
```

and then your view would call some method and print the menu afterwards.

EDIT

Let's consider this switch-case, which is part of the menu

```
        switch (foodMenuTypes){
            case BREAKFASTMENU -> {return foodMenu.getBreakfastMenu();}
            case LUNCHMENU -> {return foodMenu.getLunchMenu();}
            case DINNERMENU -> {return foodMenu.getDinnerMenu();}
        }
```

Where does this logic belong to? Is it part of the view? Or the controller?

Let's think about it this way: if we are to implement a graphical UI, then where do we want this switch-case to be part of? The answer is simple: we want this to be in the controller, because that way we can easily implement the new UI, which will have some `getDinnerMenu` and other similar methods that would be responsible of graphically displaying the menu.

On the other hand, if we leave this switch-case inside the view, then, in our scenario of reimplementing the user-interface we will have to go through the view code line-by-line and find what we need to keep from it. However, if, at the time of totally reimplementing the view we have parts of the view to keep, then we have an error in our architectural design. So, how could we move this logic into the controller? The answer is not difficult at all:

- we create a controller method
- which will have this switch-case
- returning the result of view methods
- depending on what value was chosen in the view

Reason: Even though the value was chosen in the view and subsequently the choice has to be parsed by the view, deciding what template to load is a logical question and logical questions are deemed to be answered in the controller.

So, you will have a controller method like this:

```
public SomeViewClass doMyStuff(int input) {
    switch (input) {
        case SOMEVALUE1: return someView.getSomeViewClass1();
        case SOMEVALUE2: return someView.getSomeViewClass2();
        case SOMEVALUE3: return someView.getSomeViewClass3();
        //...
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

and from the view, just call `doMyStuff` and pass the options. The namings above were arbitrary, you of course should namings that are better representing your entities.

Comment: I edit my code a little to make it follow the MVC pattern. Could you check it again to see does it fit with the requirement or not?

Comment: @DavidMoore it's much closer to the MVC pattern now. I would move the switch-case chunks from the view into the controller, because that's already the control part and it is better suited in the controller. Otherwise it looks good! I would like to kindly ask you to edit your question and make sure that the initial version of your code is still present, so future readers of your question will understand where we started our thinking process from.

Comment: I have already save the previous version of my code in github.com so I will post it later. By the way, I don't know how to move the switch-case into controller? Since I think that when I look at the Menu option screen and insert the option to choose Food Menu or Drink Menu. Does that kind of change happen in View? Can you give me some code example about how to move switch-case to controller but still keep the code logic like this. Thanks so much for your support. I am really appreciated.

Comment: @DavidMoore edited my answer and added further information.

Comment: I edit my code as your comment. Do you think that it stick with the MVC pattern more or not? Thanks for your support.

Comment: @DavidMoore now your code is sticking to the MVC pattern more, I would accept it as an MVC code.

Comment: My mentor want me to change from MVC pattern to three tier architecture, which separates completely the data layer from presentation layer, he want that the Objects: Bill and Menu cannot be create at Main class and also the parameter of methods in Daily Menu Services should not contain DailyMenu( which you can get if you have database). Do I need to create database to store my values and create Query for CRUD operation in services or I only need to create another class to store values in the same JVM. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @DavidMoore it is possible, but not necessary. Your controller can instantiate model classes and use view templates. This means that your `Main` class will need to call controller methods and it is your controller that will call model and view methods. You can also use a database if you prefer or some other means to store your data, but only if that's adding some value to your project. You will need to ask yourself whether you need the data created during the program's running in the future or not.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. From the first day, I learn about Java I have a lot of questions in my mind and sometimes I find out it is difficult to look for the solutions , since the answer for MVC pattern focus more on Web developing rather than single JVM structure like I have studied recently. Most of tutorials use simple example to demonstrate the MVC pattern which makes it's harder for me find out solution when it comes to more complex structure like this. Hope you success in your lives and career Lajos Arpad. Keep it up, your work inspires me to keep looking forward to enhance my code.

Comment: Extra: I am finding back our first comment code since I lost it by accident. Hopefully, our work will support another person problems.

Comment: @DavidMoore apparently some of our comments were removed by the moderators. Nevertheless, it's good that you have managed to overcome the difficulties. I think our discussions will help future visitors facing similar problems or questions. You might consider accepting this answer if it was helpful. Anyway, thanks for your kind words and I wish you a great time while you are coding.